# The ::after is not working in my development website

Tags: css, sass

i use this after in SCSS but i don't see anything.

```
  &::after {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0%;
    width: 216px;
    height: 254px;
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    background: url(../images/life_history.svg) center/contain no-repeat;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you forgot to add the content property in the CSS code: `content: '';`

Answer (score 0):

**you are missing** `content: "";`

```
&::after {
content: ""; // This line was missing
position: absolute;
right: 0;
top: 0%;
width: 216px;
height: 254px;
transform: rotateY(180deg);
background: url(../images/life_history.svg) center/contain no-repeat;
```

}